# MongoDB Atlas Cluster Connection Problem with Authentication Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, git, git-bash, mongodb-atlas

I am not able to connect to the mongoDB Atlas cluster that I have made. I entered in the given line of code after I created the cluster and recieved the error:

I am not able to find any solution to this problem. Please help me.

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.0
Enter password: Cannot get console mode 6
connecting to: mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-01-jigfx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-jigfx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-00-jigfx.mongodb.net:27017/test?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&ssl=true
2019-09-03T17:07:19.299-0400 I  NETWORK  [js] Starting new replica set monitor for Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-01-jigfx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-jigfx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-00-jigfx.mongodb.net:27017
2019-09-03T17:07:19.300-0400 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-01-jigfx.mongodb.net:27017
2019-09-03T17:07:19.300-0400 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02-jigfx.mongodb.net:27017
2019-09-03T17:07:19.300-0400 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00-jigfx.mongodb.net:27017
2019-09-03T17:07:20.099-0400 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] 
Confirmed replica set for Cluster0-shard-0 is Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-jigfx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-jigfx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-jigfx.mongodb.net:27017
2019-09-03T17:07:20.719-0400 I  NETWORK  [js] Marking host cluster0-shard-00-00-jigfx.mongodb.net:27017 as failed :: caused by :: Location40659:can't connect to new replica set master [cluster0-shard-00-00-jigfx.mongodb.net:27017], err: AuthenticationFailed: Missing expected field "pwd"


*** It looks like this is a MongoDB Atlas cluster. Please ensure that your IP whitelist allows connections from your network.


2019-09-03T17:07:21.522-0400 E  QUERY    [js] Error: Missing expected field "pwd" :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2019-09-03T17:07:21.524-0400 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2019-09-03T17:07:21.524-0400 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

The expected result is a prompt that asks me for the password to connect to the cluster, but the prompt instantly responds with Cannot get console mode 6

Comment: Have you [Added an IP Whitelist](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/#add-whitelist-entries) entry? Are you using the [shell command](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/mongo-shell-connection/) provided in the Connect dialog?

Comment: have you find solution for this.? I stuck with same issue.

Comment: Checkout this link for answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59910899/12028348

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try adding `--password ****` to the end of command