# MongoDB Atlas connection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

hello can anybody help me with this error

```
$ mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0-zdzwa.mongodb.net/test"  --username admin-dalia
MongoDB shell version v4.2.6
Enter password: Cannot get console mode 6
connecting to: mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-02-zdzwa.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-00-zdzwa.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-zdzwa.mongodb.net:27017/test?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&ssl=true
2020-05-01T18:00:58.985+0300 I  NETWORK  [js] Starting new replica set monitor for Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-02-zdzwa.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-00-zdzwa.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-zdzwa.mongodb.net:27017
2020-05-01T18:00:58.986+0300 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02-zdzwa.mongodb.net:27017
2020-05-01T18:00:58.986+0300 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-01-zdzwa.mongodb.net:27017
2020-05-01T18:00:58.986+0300 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00-zdzwa.mongodb.net:27017
2020-05-01T18:00:59.983+0300 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Confirmed replica set for Cluster0-shard-0 is Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-zdzwa.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-zdzwa.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-zdzwa.mongodb.net:27017
2020-05-01T18:01:00.530+0300 I  NETWORK  [js] Marking host cluster0-shard-00-01-zdzwa.mongodb.net:27017 as failed :: caused by :: Location40659: can't connect to new replica set master [cluster0-shard-00-01-zdzwa.mongodb.net:27017], err: AuthenticationFailed: Missing expected field "pwd"
```

> It looks like this is a MongoDB Atlas cluster. Please ensure that your IP whitelist allows connections from your network.

```
2020-05-01T18:01:00.530+0300 E  QUERY    [js] Error: can't connect to new replica set master [cluster0-shard-00-01-zdzwa.mongodb.net:27017], err: AuthenticationFailed: Missing expected field "pwd" :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6


----------


2020-05-01T18:01:00.533+0300 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-05-01T18:01:00.533+0300 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your IP to whitelist.
In your mongoAtlas there is a tab securicy -> network access -> add there 0.0.0.0
This will allow access from any IP from web.

Comment: Try this
https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/#add-whitelist-entries

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59228986/mongodb-cant-connect-to-new-replica-set-master/59910899#59910899

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the error it looks like you didn't or can't enter your password.

```
$ mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0-zdzwa.mongodb.net/test"  --username admin-dalia
MongoDB shell version v4.2.6
Enter password: Cannot get console mode 6
```

The error from Atlas is:

```
err: AuthenticationFailed: Missing expected field "pwd"
```

pwd is a short name for `password`.

Try passing it in with the `--password` argument.

You might also try [Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) which allows you to paste the connection string straight into the tool as a way to validate that you are doing the right thing.